# Multiplying rasters by integers in processing modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to multiply several rasters by integers as a part of a multiple steps process. For this reason I'm using QGIS' Processing Modeler.

I'm looking for something similar to the `Raster calculator`, but it doesn't seem to be available from the Processing Modeler.

I've also tried to use the GRASS `r.mapcalculator` algorithm (with `A` my input raster layer, and applying the formula `A*100` for example), but it always returns the following error message:

```
Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
Output raster layer: /tmp/processing/ad0f2935615a472eb6b6b6feb44f3e72/outfile.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Raster Product`. In the captured image, `Constant grid` will create a raster layer with cell values defined in the `Value` input. Then  `Raster product` will multiply `Input Raster` and `Constant grid` raster.

(1) `SAGA | Raster tools | Constant grid`

(2) `SAGA | Raster calculus | Raster product`

[image]